# Update prettify highligher for this site

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, syntax-highlighting

Mathematica version 10 has been released, with new functions and operators.

The syntax highlighter on this site needs to be updated.

The highlighter that is being used is already updated [in the GitHub repo](https://github.com/halirutan/Mathematica-Source-Highlighting).  The new version simply needs to be added to this site.

Comment: Nice point. Association are just ugly today :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a bug in the updated version. I've sent you [a pull request](https://github.com/halirutan/Mathematica-Source-Highlighting/pull/5) with the fix (you'll have to regenerate the other files) and updated our version, including this fix. The new version is now live.

Thanks for the update!

Comment: Thanks for the update, I'll pass that on to the author of the highlighter.